# integral of exponentials

Tags: integration, exponential-function, laplace-transform

I have difficulties to solve the following integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1} {x} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{a}}  (\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-(\frac{x-c}{b})}}) dx $$

I wanted to compute it by using Laplace Transform, but $\frac{1}{x}$ part made me confused and I could not reach to a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral won't converge, because
$$\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{a}}  (\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-(\frac{x-c}{b})}}) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{c}{b}}}+o(1)$$
Around $0$.

Comment: Thank you, great help! @Botond